# Show that:$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{n\over (4n^2-1)(16n^2-1)}={1\over 12}(1-\ln{2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n\over (4n^2-1)(16n^2-1)}={1\over 12}(1-\ln{2})$$

My try:

We split into partial decomposition

$$n={A\over 2n-1}+{B\over 2n+1}+{C\over 4n-1}+{D\over 4n+1}$$

Setting $n={1\over 2}$, ${-1\over2}$ we have $A={1\over3}$ and $B={-1\over 3}$

Finding C and D is a bit tedious

I wonder what is the closed form for

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over an+b}=F(a,b)?$$

This way is not a good approach. Can anyone help me with a better approach to tackle this problem? Thank you.

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{n}{(4n^2-1)(16n^2-1)} = \frac{1/12}{2n-1} + \frac{1/12}{2n+1} + \frac{-1/6}{4n-1}+ \frac{-1/6}{4n+1}$

Comment: This formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm_of_2#Series_representations) seems useful $$\ln 2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} $$

Comment: $$ \psi(x+1) = -\gamma + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+x}\right) \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+a}-\frac{1}{n+b}\right) = \psi(b+1) - \psi(a+1) $$

Comment: This reduces to summing over $$\frac{1}{4n - 2}  + \frac{1}{4n + 2} - \frac{1}{4n - 1} - \frac{1}{4n + 1}$$ which can be simplified further to summing up reciprocals of the positive odd numbers, which may be where the $\ln 2$ comes from. However the $\ln2$ is apparently cancelled.

Comment: $$ \frac{n}{(4n^2-1)(16n^2-1)} = \frac{1}{24}\left[\left(\frac{1}{n-1/2} - \frac{1}{n-1/4}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{n+1/2} - \frac{1}{n+1/4}\right)\right] \\ \small \psi\left(\frac12\right) = - 2\log2 - \gamma \space,\quad \psi\left(\frac14\right) = - \frac{\pi}{2} - 3\log2 - \gamma \space,\quad \psi\left(x+1\right) = \psi\left(x\right) + \frac1x $$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we consider
$$ f(x)=\frac{x}{(4x^2-1)(16x^2-1)} $$
we may compute its partial fraction decomposition through the residue theorem:
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{24}\left(\frac{1}{x-\tfrac{1}{2}}+\frac{1}{x+\tfrac{1}{2}}\right)-\frac{1}{24}\left(\frac{1}{x-\tfrac{1}{4}}+\frac{1}{x+\tfrac{1}{4}}\right)$$
and that leads to:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 1}f(n) &=& \frac{1}{6}\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{4n-2}+\frac{1}{4n+2}-\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{4n+1}\right) \\&=&\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(x^{4n-3}+x^{4n+1}-x^{4n-2}-x^{4n}\right)\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(1-x)(1-x^3)}{1-x^4}\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{6}\left(\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)\,dx-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x)^2}{1-x^4}\,dx\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{6}\left(\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)\,dx-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x+1}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\,dx\right)\\&=&\frac{1-\log 2}{12}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Nice answer but I think the last integral will be quite complicated ? Or maybe just look up its anti-derivative.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: it is not complicated, since we may apply partial fraction decomposition again: $$\frac{(1-x)^2}{1-x^4}=\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{x}{x^2+1}$$ and its primitive is clearly $$\log(x+1)-\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+1)$$

Comment: Oh, you should get more votes for that concise answer.

Answer (score 6):

Note that

$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n\over (4n^2-1)(16n^2-1)}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{12n}\left\{\frac{1}{4n^2-1}-\frac{1}{16n^2-1} \right\}$$

Hence

$$ \frac{1}{12n}\left\{\frac{1}{4n^2-1}-\frac{1}{16n^2-1} \right\}=   \frac{1}{24n}\left\{\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{4n+1}-\frac{1}{4n-1} \right\}$$

Using the digamma function we have

$$S = \frac{1}{24}\left\{- \psi \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\psi \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)+\psi \left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \right \}  = \frac{1}{12}(1-\log 2)$$

Since

$$\psi(x+1) = -\gamma + \sum \frac{x}{n(n+x)}$$

Note that

$$\psi\left(\frac{1}{2} \right) = -\gamma -2\log(2)$$

$$\psi\left(\frac{1}{4} \right) = -\gamma -\frac{\pi}{2}-3\log(2)$$

$$\psi(1+x) = \psi(x)+\frac{1}{x}$$
$$\psi(1-x) = \psi(x)+\pi \cot(\pi x)$$

Comment: I was just checking your blog @Zaid Alyafeai. Interesting integrals.

Comment: @X-men, these are part of the book I created. You can find it in the blog.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the decomposition
$$\frac{n}{(4n^2-1)(16n^2-1)}=\frac{1/12}{2n-1}+\frac{1/12}{2n+1}+\frac{-1/6}{4n+1}+\frac{-1/6}{4n-1}$$
Then let $H_N=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}=\log(N)+\gamma+o(1)$

You can compute $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2n}=H_{2N}-H_N/2$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{1}{2n-1}-1=H_{2N+2}-H_{N+1}/2-1$$

And, $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{4n-1} + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{4n+1} + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{4n} + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{4n-2} = \sum_{n=2}^{4N+1} \frac{1}{n} = H_{4N+1}-1 $$
Hence, $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{4n-1} + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{4n+1} = H_{4N+1} - 1 - (1/2) \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2n-1} -(1/4)H_N$$

At this point you can compute your sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1/12}{2n-1}+\frac{1/12}{2n+1}+\frac{-1/6}{4n+1}+\frac{-1/6}{4n-1} = \frac{1}{12}H_{2N} - \frac{1}{24}H_N +\frac{1}{12} H_{2N+2} - \frac{1}{12} -\frac{1}{24}H_{N+1} -\frac{1}{6} \left(H_{4N+1} -1 -\frac{1}{2}H_{2N} + \frac{1}{4}H_N - \frac{1}{4} H_N \right)$$
You can use the development with $\gamma$, and you get:
$$\frac{1}{6}\log(2N)+\frac{1}{6}\gamma -\frac{1}{24} \log(N) - \frac{1}{24}\gamma+\frac{1}{12}\log(2N+2) + \frac{1}{12}\gamma + \frac{1}{12} - \frac{1}{24}\log(N+1) - \frac{1}{24}\gamma - \frac{1}{6}\gamma - \frac{1}{6}\log(4N+1) + o(1)$$
You notice that all the $\gamma$ term vanish and you compute the equivalent when $N$ goes to $\infty$ (mainly replace $N+1$ by $N$), all the $\log(N)$ terms vanish too and you get $$\frac{1}{6}\log(2) + \frac{1}{12}\log(2) + \frac{1}{12} - \frac{1}{6}\log(4) = \frac{1}{12} - \frac{\log(2)}{12} $$

Comment: Great answer! But I don't see how the $\log(N)$ terms at the end vanish, could you please tell me something more about that?

Comment: @John11 at the end when you compute the equivalent, use $\log(4N+1) \sim \log(4N) = \log(4)+\log(N)$. Finally if you consider all the $\log(N)$ terms you have $\log(N)(1/6-1/24+1/12-1/24-1/6)$ which is 0

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! +1

Answer (score 0):

$\left(\frac{1}{an+b}\right)_{\substack{n\in\mathbb{N}\\an+b\neq0}}$ is not summable if $a\neq0$ (this has the same behavior as the harmonic series). Thus $\sum\frac{1}{an+b}$ diverges, and your $F(a,b)$ is not well-defined.

However you can sum up to some integer $N$, and use an asymptotic development of:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{an+b}=\frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n+\frac{b}{a}}$$

This can be done typically with a comparison with an integral.

---

UPD: Actually you just need to know an asymptotic estimation of the harmonic series:

$$H_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}=\log(n)+\gamma+o(1)$$

Because:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n+\lfloor{\frac{b}{a}}\rfloor+1}<\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n+\frac{b}{a}}\le\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n+\lfloor\frac{b}{a}\rfloor}$$

Thus:

$$\sum_{n=1+\lfloor{\frac{b}{a}}\rfloor+1}^{N+\lfloor{\frac{b}{a}}\rfloor+1}\frac{1}{n}<\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n+\frac{b}{a}}\le\sum_{n=1+\lfloor{\frac{b}{a}}\rfloor}^{N+\lfloor{\frac{b}{a}}\rfloor}\frac{1}{n}$$

i.e.

$$H_{N+\lfloor{\frac{b}{a}}\rfloor+1}-H_{1+\lfloor{\frac{b}{a}}\rfloor}<\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n+\frac{b}{a}}\le H_{N+\lfloor\frac{b}{a}\rfloor}-H_{\lfloor\frac{b}{a}\rfloor}$$

---

Ok, let's write it.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{an+b}=\frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n+\frac{b}{a}}$$

According to our previous estimations: $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{an+b}=\frac{1}{a}\log(N)+O(1)$. But actually we need a $o(1)$ precision. So let $\epsilon_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{an+b}-\frac{1}{a}\log(N)$.

$$\epsilon_{N}-\epsilon_{N-1}=\frac{1}{aN+b}-\frac{1}{a}(\log(N)-\log(N-1))=\frac{1}{aN+b}+\frac{1}{a}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)$$

So, using asymptotic estimations of $\log(1+x)$ and $\frac{1}{1+x}$ in $x=0$:

$$\epsilon_{N}-\epsilon_{N-1} = \frac{1}{aN}\left(1-\frac{b}{aN}+o\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{a}\left(-\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{2N^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{N^2}\right)\right)
\sim \frac{C}{N^2}$$

with $C=-\frac{b}{a^2}-\frac{1}{2a}$

Summing equivalents there exists $C'$ s.t. $\epsilon_N = C' - \frac{C}{N}+o\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)$

---

Now we can solve the original problem, using the partial decomposition-form and adding our estimations.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't think that you are actually answering the OP...

Comment: @JeanMarie: Oh, why? I mean, once the partial decomposition is done, IMO it should lead to the answer.

Comment: How do you obtain the answer ${1\over 12}(1-\ln{2})$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: Well if we get a $o(1)$-estimation of $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{an+b}$, we just have to sum the developments of the members of the partial decomposition to get the limit of $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{n}{(4n^2-1)(16n^2-1)}$.

Comment: But how do you do it ? Give a hint of how can $\ln(2)$ spring out.